# How to export images to excel from gridview?

Tags: c#, asp.net, excel, gridview

Here I am exporting gridview to excel,in my gridview i have some images i want to export images also.here i am attaching may code. here i am using EPPlus

```
 var products = GetProducts();
        gvDetails.DataSource = products;
        gvDetails.DataBind();
        ExcelPackage excel = new ExcelPackage();
        var workSheet = excel.Workbook.Worksheets.Add("Products");
        var totalCols = gvDetails.Rows[0].Cells.Count;
        var totalRows = gvDetails.Rows.Count;
        var headerRow = gvDetails.HeaderRow;
        for (var col = 1; col <= totalCols; col++)
        {
            workSheet.Cells[1, col].Value = products.Columns[col - 1].ColumnName;
        }
        for (var row = 1; row <= totalRows; row++)
        {

            for (var col = 0; col < totalCols; col++)
            {

                workSheet.Cells[row + 1, col + 1].Value = products.Rows[row - 1][col];


            }
        }
        using (var memoryStream = new MemoryStream())
        {
            Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet";
            Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment;  filename=products.xlsx");
            excel.SaveAs(memoryStream);
            memoryStream.WriteTo(Response.OutputStream);
            Response.Flush();
            Response.End();
        }



public DataTable GetProducts()
    {
        using (var conn = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["dbconnection"].ConnectionString))
        using (var cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM Glines", conn))
        using (var adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd))
        {
            var products = new DataTable();
            adapter.Fill(products);       
 return products;
        }
    }
```

here i am attaching my database table(glines) snap also.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Fsz0y.png)

Answer (score 0):

Here is a working sample

```
 <form id="form1" runat="server">
        <div>
            <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False">
                <Columns>
                    <asp:BoundField DataField="Name" HeaderText="Name" />
                    <asp:BoundField DataField="Job" HeaderText="Job" />
                    <asp:BoundField DataField="Location" HeaderText="Location" />
                    <asp:ImageField DataImageUrlField="Image" HeaderText="Image">
                    </asp:ImageField>
                </Columns>

            </asp:GridView>
        </div>

        <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Button" onclick="Button1_Click" />
        </form>

protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (!IsPostBack)
            {
                GridView1.DataSource = GetTable();
                GridView1.DataBind();
            }
        }
        static DataTable GetData()
        {
            DataTable table = new DataTable();
            table.Columns.Add("Name", typeof(string));
            table.Columns.Add("Job", typeof(string));
            table.Columns.Add("Location", typeof(string));
            table.Columns.Add("Image");

            table.Rows.Add("JP", "XXX", "QQQQ", "http://localhost:4832/images/JP.png");
            table.Rows.Add("HP", "TTT", "AAAA", "http://localhost:4832/images/HP.png");
            table.Rows.Add("SQ", "YYY", "HHHH", "http://localhost:4832/images/SQ.png");
            table.Rows.Add("XS", "EEE", "UUUU", "http://localhost:4832/images/XS.png");
            return table;
        }

        protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Response.ClearContent();
            Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment; filename=test.xls");
            Response.ContentType = "application/excel";
            System.IO.StringWriter sw = new System.IO.StringWriter();
            HtmlTextWriter htw = new HtmlTextWriter(sw);
            GridView1.RenderControl(htw);
            Response.Write(sw.ToString());
            Response.End();
        }
        public override void VerifyRenderingInServerForm(Control control)
        {

        }
```

Comment: i tried above code. it's successfully worked for me.but the generated excel file should not be in the proper format. and the image shown very big in the document,so i am trying with the above code.